# Creating an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

In rails, when creating an initializer, is it as simple as adding a file to the config/initializer director or do I need to make changes elsewhere?

I'm asking because I keep getting errors every time I create an initializer for gems...and not sure if it's because I'm missing a step in creating initializers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

initializers are just files in `config/initializers` there is no other magic

Comment: when you add a new initializer you'll also need to restart your local server, just a simple browser refresh will not pull in the newly created initializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a plugin or gem though, you may need to explicitly "request" or "require" the plugin in your controllers too...in that case, you'll just need to look at the documentation.